# Wie spricht man "Friedrich III." aus?

Tags: pronunciation, politeness, address

Zum Beispiel, "Friedrich Drei" oder "Friedrich der Dritte"?

Comment: http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Satzgliedbau/Nomen/Apposition.html#Anchor-Apposition-3800 http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adjektiv/Zahlen/Ordinal.html

Comment: @mle Sie haben recht. Ein Duplikat ist meine Frage.